# Hardware and software to get SMART status from an external USB SSD?

Tags: macos, usb, ssd, driver

Is there any combination of hardware (any SSD drive) and software (a driver) to be able to get SMART status from an external USB SSD? My development writes constantly to my WD SSD without SMART status and I have no way to know if it's about to fail.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are combinations that will allow that. Specifically you will need to look for an external USB enclosure that supports SAT (SCSI ATA Translation).

A popular tool for accessing SMART data is the `smartmontools` suite. They have a [list of USB bridges](https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/USB) that support SAT that they also support. Note the paragraph regarding macOS at the bottom.

They also have a [list of supported devices](https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/Supported_USB-Devices), although it is relatively limited in that many more devices exists that actually do work, but are not on the list.

Comment: Thanks, I have seen info like that with its caveats. I am hoping that someone who has bought hardware and then successfully used a driver can share exactly what they did to make it work.

Comment: I did it like described on that link - however USB enclosures and external hard disk products are short lived. The products that were good a few years ago are probably no longer made. Are you looking to purchase a new disk, or just an enclosure? Or do you want to get the existing hardware working?

Comment: A new 1 TB SSD as boot disk. I’ve been writing to this WD drive constantly (continuously writing processing data) for over six months and I dread losing it all suddenly. The speed gain was tremendous over the build-in iMac HD. Thanks.

Comment: If you dread loosing the data, I would recommend backups. Just replacing the drive with a newer drive is not really a replacement for good backups. How much data exactly have you been continuously writing to your drive? Nowadays SSDs in general have no problem being written to all day for years. However if you’re talking extreme amounts of data then yes, you could definitely wear out the drive early.

Comment: I’m backing up only once a day (Time Machine takes about six hours and bogs it down, so at night, also an offsite backup). It’s writing data as fast as it can continuously (and reading it back), plus using VM (only 32GB RAM), but I haven’t calculated how much this is in a year. I just want to see the wear value so I can replace it in time.

Comment: I just hope someone can say what they bought that returns the SMART wear value.

Comment: Are you saying that you’re writing to the drive as fast as it can continuously 24/7? Or just for a limited amount of time while storing a backup? … It is not a good idea to use the wear value for replacing the drive before it fails. The wear value only concerns a single factor in drive life time - the drive can fail for many different reasons well before it wears out. In addition to that, the wear value is just an estimate put on it by the vendor - it is not an actual indication of the wear. Wear a drive 100% and it might still live on for years - or it could fail completely at 50% wear.

Comment: The disk you choose is not that important in that regard - they all support SMART. You need to choose the right enclosure as indicated on the links I gave you.

Comment: Maybe I missed something. In “I did it like described on that link” do you mean you bought an external USB SSD with enclosure that returns SMART status to Mac? I want to buy one item, no assembly required.

Comment: I’m happy to keep the existing as an additional backup device.

Comment: Are you sure this is wise? You have avoided answering any questions on determining whether this is a good idea. I.e. 1) exactly how much are you writing to that disk - are you sure you’re overreacting, and 2) do backups - not replacements based on a wear counter. Note that if you can explain q 1) then you can calculate the smart wear indicator reply without actually using smart.

Comment: No problem! I take it you found a product that works, so I don't need to dig out the product number here.

Comment: I don’t live close enough to a store to have gotten it by now. But just a brand name of SSD with enclosure (one box) would be helpful.